# Javascript search in innerHtml Exclude html tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a custom search in *javascript* for highlighting texts.

the scenario is to get `innerHtml` and search for the text and highlight them.

**the problem**: if the user search for ***i*** the ***i*** in the `<div>` tag were found and everything messed up.

```
var textBlock=document.body.innerHTML;
searchIndex = textBlock.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase(), 0);
while(searchIndex >= 0)
{
    ++counter;
    ID = "result" + counter;
    replacement = '<span id='+ID+' style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';
    textBlock = textBlock.substring(0, searchIndex) + replacement + textBlock.substring(searchIndex + what.length, textBlock.length);
    searchIndex = textBlock.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase(), (searchIndex + replacement.length));
}
document.body.innerHTML=textBlock;
```

what can i do to skip founded index in tags?

something like this:

```
if(isTag(searchIndex))
    //do nothing
```

**UPDATE:**

if i use `innerText` instead of `innerHtml` then all of my text format and style will be ruind.

```
var textBlock=document.body.innerText;
document.body.innerHTML=textBlock;
```

Comment: Search from the `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`?

Comment: @Teemu can we add span in `textContent` ?

Comment: That part of the code will need some fix if `textContent` will be used.

Comment: @Teemu if i use `textContent` then how to show the results in view, now the `document.body.innerHTML=textBlock;` will update the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to work with nodes:

- Get the `body` child nodes (instead of the `innerHTML`)
- Traverse the nodes:

  - If it's a text node (leaf): search for the string to replace.
  - If it's an element node: get and traverse the children.

Here is a sample function that will highlight the text that you specify:

```
function highlightText(nodeList, what) {

  // traverse all the children nodes
  for (var x = 0; x < nodeList.length; x++) {

    // text node, search directly
    if (nodeList[x].nodeType == 3) {

      // if it contains the text that you are looking for, proceed with the replacement
      if (nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what) >= 0) {

        // your code (mostly :P)
        var ID = "result" + counter;
        var replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';
        var textBlock = nodeList[x].textContent;
        var searchIndex = nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what);
        while(searchIndex >= 0)
        {
          ++counter;
          ID = "result" + counter;
          replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';           
          textBlock = textBlock.substring(0, searchIndex) + replacement + textBlock.substring(searchIndex + what.length, textBlock.length);
          searchIndex = textBlock.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase(), (searchIndex + replacement.length));
        }

        // create a new element with the replacement text
        var replacementNode = document.createElement("span");
        replacementNode.innerHTML = textBlock;

        // replace the old node with the new one
        var parentN = nodeList[x].parentNode;
        parentN.replaceChild(replacementNode, parentN.childNodes[x]);

      }
    } else {
      // element node --> search in its children nodes
      highlightText(nodeList[x].childNodes, what);
    }
  }
}
```

---

And here is a sample demo (also available on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tkm5696w/)):

```js
var counter = 0;

function highlightText(nodeList, what) {

  // traverse all the children nodes
  for (var x = 0; x < nodeList.length; x++) {

    // text node, search directly
    if (nodeList[x].nodeType == 3) {

      // if it contains the text that you are looking for, proceed with the replacement
      if (nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what) >= 0) {

        // your code (mostly :P)
        var ID = "result" + counter;
        var replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';
        var textBlock = nodeList[x].textContent;
        var searchIndex = nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what);
        while(searchIndex >= 0)
        {
          ++counter;
          ID = "result" + counter;
          replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';   
          textBlock = textBlock.substring(0, searchIndex) + replacement + textBlock.substring(searchIndex + what.length, textBlock.length);
          searchIndex = textBlock.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase(), (searchIndex + replacement.length));
        }

        // create a new element with the replacement text
        var replacementNode = document.createElement("span");
        replacementNode.innerHTML = textBlock;

        // replace the old node with the new one
        var parentN = nodeList[x].parentNode;
        parentN.replaceChild(replacementNode, parentN.childNodes[x]);

      }
    } else {
      // element node --> search in its children nodes
      highlightText(nodeList[x].childNodes, what);
    }
  }
}

var nodes = document.body.childNodes;
console.log(nodes);
highlightText(nodes, "ar");
```

```html
<p>Men at some time are masters of their fates: The fault, dear Brutus, is not in our stars, but in ourselves, that we are underlings.</p>
<p><b>William Shakespeare</b>, <em>Julius Caesar</em> (Act I, Scene II)</p>
```

One issue with this solution is that it adds additional `span` elements wrapping each text node that contained the searched string (although I don't know how big of an inconvenience that may be for you). It is also recursive, you may want to look into an iterative alternative.

---

**UPDATE.** I know you didn't ask for this, but I thought it could be interesting: by reordering the parameters list, and adding some initialization on the first call, you can make the function cleaner for the user, and at the same time, add some interesting functionality:

```
function highlightText(what, node) {

    // initialize values if first call
    node = node || document.body;
    var nodeList = node.childNodes;

    // traverse all the children nodes
    for (var x = 0; x < nodeList.length; x++) {

        // text node, search directly
        if (nodeList[x].nodeType == 3) {

            // if it contains the text that you are looking for, proceed with the replacement
            if (nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what) >= 0) {

                // your code (mostly :P)
                var ID = "result" + counter;
                var replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';
                var textBlock = nodeList[x].textContent;
                var searchIndex = nodeList[x].textContent.indexOf(what);
                while(searchIndex >= 0)
                {
                    ++counter;
                    ID = "result" + counter;
                    replacement = '<span id="'+ID+'" style="background-color:#f0da1e">'+what+'</span>';         
                    textBlock = textBlock.substring(0, searchIndex) + replacement + textBlock.substring(searchIndex + what.length, textBlock.length);
                    searchIndex = textBlock.toLowerCase().indexOf(what.toLowerCase(), (searchIndex + replacement.length));
                }

                // create a new element with the replacement text
                var replacementNode = document.createElement("span");
                replacementNode.innerHTML = textBlock;

                // replace the old node with the new one
                var parentN = nodeList[x].parentNode;
                parentN.replaceChild(replacementNode, parentN.childNodes[x]);

            }
        } else {
            // element node --> search in its children nodes
            highlightText(what, nodeList[x]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to search a string within the page, you can simply do:

```
highlightText("ar");
```

(No second parameter needed as before)

But if you pass an element as a second parameter to the function, then the search will be performed exclusively within the specified element and not in the whole page:

```
highlightText("ar", document.getElementById("highlight_only_this"));
```

You can see a demo working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tkm5696w/2/

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.
You can use `element.textContent`.

Differences between `innerText` and `textContent` can be in the below link.

[MDN - textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Internet Explorer introduced `element.innerText`. The intention is similar but with the following differences:

1. While textContent gets the content of all elements, including
    and  elements, the IE-specific property innerText
   does not.
2. innerText is aware of style and will not return the text of hidden
   elements, whereas textContent will.
3. As innerText is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow,
   whereas textContent will not.

Comment: would OP lose the rest of the styling when highlighting the text?

Comment: @Mike how can you wrap a letter with span using innerText or textContent ? (the only thing that matter in the OP question)

Comment: @Mike please see my edited question, in i use `innerText` my html format will be ruined.

Answer (score 0):

innerHtml will search for both text and elements inside given element. Use innerText or textContent to only search for text (I understand that is what you want)

Comment: please see my edited question, in i use innerText my html format will be ruined.